# How to prevent the JSP/JSF file from changing when it is deployed?

Tags: jsp, jsf, war

I would like to seal and protect my WAR file, especially the JSP/JSF from changing when it is deployed to the application server(Tomcat, Glassfish, etc.), with purpose to make sure that the artifacts is consistent among the production, UAT, SIT, DEV environment, so that I can reproduce any issue and speed up my fixing phase.

I also know that the quick fix for trivial issue about JSP/JSF (the label spelling, the font size, etc.) directly to the production artifact may be acceptable. Anyhow it is a tricky. If there is any wrong, I would prefer to go back to the process and release the new version.

At the moment, I use jar-signer to sing the WAR file. It can protect the Java classes, but not the JSP/JSF. Could you please help to advise further? Thank you very much for help in advance. I'm looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Regards,

Charlee Ch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look on a [LiveRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/liverebel/) tool which allows "ninja updates" mode for the quick fixes.

Comment: Do we have any open source tools like this?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. It is possible to do some trickery with Jenkins/shell scripts and some monitoring tool like zabbix and write some supporting logic into the application itself. Quite troublesome, I should say.

Answer (score 1):

You can see JRebel tool. I think there are free version.

Comment: JRebel is a development tool and is not meant to be used in production environments.